# DML does not work on bigquery table which are connected to google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have to update the sheet data which has been consolidated in BigQuery.

Is there a possible solution for that?

What I was trying to do is to keep an extra column, `is_consolidated`, in the table with Google Sheet.

And update it, once it has been aggregated by scheduled queries

Comment: What do you mean by consolidated? Are you using the federated table and materializing it to a Native table in BQ? As soon as you change data in the sheet, you'll have to materialize it again. If your query is idempotent, you can schedule  the query every 6 hours or even every hours is this is crucial for you.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to process the rows which gets processed once.